# NoesisGUI - Loading PNG in Noesis.Image Element

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am having troubles assigning a png image to Image element in XAML. At runtime the application crashes with exception:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

My steps are as follows:

1. App.xaml.cs

   `protected override TextureProvider GetTextureProvider()
       {
           EmbeddedTexture[] textures =
           {
               new EmbeddedTexture {filename="icon.png", resource="icon"},
               new EmbeddedTexture {filename="download.jpg", resource="download"}
           };
           return new EmbeddedTextureProvider(textures, Properties.Resources.ResourceManager);
       }`
2. MainWindow.xaml

`<Image Source="icon.png"/>`

3. I added icon.png in project dir with build action "Resource" and added the same in Resources.resx file.

I ran the Menu3D sample from Github which loaded png images without any trouble. Can someone please point out what I might be doing wrong? I'd appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on their forums and got the workaround here:

http://www.noesisengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1404

The workaround was to edit Resources.resx file and replace "System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" with "System.Byte[], mscorlib" for every image file. Also change the getters in Resources.Designer.cs and replace "Bitmap" type with "Byte[]" type.